# Separar Colunas em Numeros de Linhas SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

to com um problema para SQL Server.

Tenho uma tabela de evento e valor e faço um join com uma outra tabela que tem varias colunas, podendo a verba ser marcada como 1 para ativo e 0 inativo.

Como pode ver na imagem a linha 1 tem o RD8 , RD10 e RD21 marcados, queria que o valor de 97,24 fosse demonstrado em linhas porem somente para os RD's marcados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ela Teria que ficar assim.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### SQL de Criação

```
CREATE TABLE PFFINANC
(
    CODCOLIGADA       INT  NOT NULL,
    CHAPA             VARCHAR (4) NOT NULL,
    ANOCOMP           SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    MESCOMP           SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    CODEVENTO         VARCHAR (4) NOT NULL,
    VALOR             RMDVALOR2 NULL,
)


    

CREATE TABLE dbo.ZMDCUSTO_PESSOAL
(
    CODCOLIGADA   INT NOT NULL,
    CODEVENTO     VARCHAR (4) NOT NULL,
    RD1           BIT NULL,
    RD2           BIT NULL,
    RD3           BIT NULL,
    RD4           BIT NULL,
    RD5           BIT NULL,
    RD6           BIT NULL,
    RD7           BIT NULL,
    RD8           BIT NULL,
    RD9           BIT NULL,
    RD10          BIT NULL,
    RD11          BIT NULL,
    RD12          BIT NULL,
    RD13          BIT NULL,
    RD14          BIT NULL,
    RD15          BIT NULL,
    RD16          BIT NULL,
    RD17          BIT NULL,
    RD18          BIT NULL,
    RD19          BIT NULL,
    RD20          BIT NULL,
    RD21          BIT NULL,
    RD22          BIT NULL,
    RD23          BIT NULL,
    RD24          BIT NULL,
    RD25          BIT NULL,
    RD26          BIT NULL,
    RD27          BIT NULL,
    RD28          BIT NULL,
    RD29          BIT NULL,
    RD30          BIT NULL,
    RECCREATEDBY  VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    RECCREATEDON  DATETIME NULL,
    RECMODIFIEDBY VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    RECMODIFIEDON DATETIME NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (CODCOLIGADA, CODEVENTO)
)
```

Comment: A Principio eu estou fazendo um Union all para cada RD..

RD1
union all
RD2
union all
....

Comment: tentou por "unpivot"? https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Não tem como modelar o banco de forma que as colunas se transformem em linhas?

Comment: Pessoal, realmente sei que a modelagem não é a ideal. 
Infelizmente não ou tão bom quanto queria em Banco de Dados então a modelagem ficou horrivel.. Mas o problema está solucionado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para isto você pode utilizar o `upivot`.

> Você pode usar os operadores relacionais PIVOT e UNPIVOT para alterar
> uma expressão com valor de tabela para outra tabela. PIVOT gira uma
> expressão com valor de tabela ao transformar os valores exclusivos de
> uma coluna na expressão em várias colunas na saída. E PIVOT executa
> agregações em que elas são necessárias em quaisquer valores de coluna
> remanescentes que forem desejados na saída final. UNPIVOT executa a
> operação oposta à PIVOT, transformando as colunas de uma expressão com
> valor de tabela em valores de coluna.

Fonte: [Documentação Microsoft Pivot e Unpivot](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15)

### Funcionamento

Para fazer o `unpivot` é muito fácil. Fazer primeiro o `SQL` com os dados normais das colunas, e as colunas que desejamos transformar em linhas. Esta parte coloquei o alias como `base`.

Depois é somente usar o comando `unpivot`, assim:

`unpivot (nomedacoluna for qualquernome in (colunas))`

- **nomedacoluna** - Nome da coluna para utilizar no `SQL` principal;
- **qualquernome** - Qualquer nome aqui, pois serve somente para o comando;
- **colunas** - As colunas que você quer transformar em linhas

O `unpivot` somente transforma as colunas em linhas se tiver valor. Por isto utilizei o comando `case` para já deixar o resultado correto e esperado.

### Exemplo

#### Estrutura

```
create table PFFINANC (
  Grupo varchar(50),
  CodEvento varchar(4),    
  Descricao varchar(100),
  Valor decimal(15, 2)
);
 
insert into PFFINANC values ('03 - Motoristas', '0003', 'Salário Família', 97.24);
insert into PFFINANC values ('05 - Manutenção', '0005', 'Salário Família', 48.62);

CREATE TABLE ZMDCUSTO_PESSOAL
(
  CodEvento varchar(4),   
  RD1 bit,
  RD2 bit,
  RD3 bit,
  RD4 bit
);

insert into ZMDCUSTO_PESSOAL values ('0003', 0, 0, 1, 1)
insert into ZMDCUSTO_PESSOAL values ('0005', 1, 0, 1, 1)
```

## SQL

```
select 
  Grupo,
  CodEvento,
  Descricao,
  Valor,
  rd
from
  (
    select
      Grupo,
      a.CodEvento,
      Descricao,
      Valor,    
      case when RD1 = 1 then 'RD1' else null end as RD1,
      case when RD2 = 1 then 'RD2' else null end as RD2,
      case when RD3 = 1 then 'RD3' else null end as RD3,
      case when RD4 = 1 then 'RD4' else null end as RD4            
    from
      PFFINANC a
      inner join ZMDCUSTO_PESSOAL b on b.CodEvento = a.CodEvento
  ) base
  unpivot (rd for colunasrd in (RD1, RD2, RD3, RD4)) as linhas
```

[Exemplo no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0ddae/2)

[Outro exemplo 01](https://dba-pro.com/como-transformar-linhas-em-colunas-no-sql-server/)

[Outro exemplo 02](https://sqlfromhell.wordpress.com/2013/08/15/transformando-colunas-em-linhas-com-unpivot/)

[Outro exemplo 03](https://www.devmedia.com.br/utilizando-os-operadores-pivot-e-unpivot-no-sql-server/27339)

**Observação:** Fiz somente com algumas colunas para postar o exemplo assim não colocando todos os campos, e também coloquei campos que achei estar faltando nas tabelas que você utilizou.

Comment: Tiedt Tech, muito obrigado.
Sabia da funcionalidade porem não sabia que iria solucionar o meu problema.

Só tive que colocar nos case when RD1 = 1 then 'RD1' else null end as RD1, um CAST pois como o RD30 e RD1 tem quantidade de caracteres diferente eu fiz com que todos tivesse o mesmo tipo de dado.

Agradecido.